# OpenCV cross-compilation fails

Tags: opencv, cross-compilation, qt

I have cross-compiled Qt on my CentOS host for my Raspberry Pi and now I want to cross-compile OpenCV with the following script:

```
CORES=4
IP=192.168.178.52
TEMP_PATH=/home/kampi/OpenCV
SYSROOT_PATH=/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot
TOOLCHAIN_PATH=/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi
INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local
WITH_QT=ON
QT_PATH=/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt

echo -e ${Yellow}"Create directories..."${Reset}
mkdir -p ${TEMP_PATH}/log ${SYSROOT_PATH}

echo -e ${Yellow}"Download OpenCV sources..."${Reset}
cd ${TEMP_PATH}
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git

echo -e ${Yellow}"Download /lib..."${Reset}
rsync -avz root@${IP}:/lib ${SYSROOT_PATH} | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/copy_lib.log
echo -e ${Yellow}"Download /usr/include..."${Reset}
rsync -avz root@${IP}:/usr/include ${SYSROOT_PATH}/usr | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/copy_usr_include.log
echo -e ${Yellow}"Download /usr/lib..."${Reset}
rsync -avz root@${IP}:/usr/lib ${SYSROOT_PATH}/usr | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/copy_usr_lib.log
echo -e ${Yellow}"Download /opt/vc..."${Reset}
rsync -avz root@${IP}:/opt/vc ${SYSROOT_PATH}/opt | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/copy_opt_vc.log
echo -e ${Yellow}"Download /usr/local..."${Reset}
rsync -avz root@${IP}:/usr/local ${SYSROOT_PATH}/usr | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/copy_usr_local.log

echo -e ${Yellow}"Change symlinks..."${Reset}
${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/sysroot-relativelinks.py ${SYSROOT_PATH}

echo -e ${Yellow}"Configure build..."${Reset}
cd ${TEMP_PATH}/opencv
mkdir -p ${TEMP_PATH}/opencv/build && cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc \
    -D CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=${SYSROOT_PATH}/opt/vc/lib \
    -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \
    -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv4 \
    -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mthumb -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv4 \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${SYSROOT_PATH}${INSTALL_PATH}/OpenCV \
    -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=${TEMP_PATH}/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=OFF \
    -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
    -D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
    -D WITH_GTK=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
    -D WITH_V4L=ON \
    -D WITH_QT=${WITH_QT} \
    -D Qt5_DIR=${QT_PATH}/lib/cmake/Qt5 \
    -D QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=${QT_PATH}/bin/qmake \
    -D Qt5Concurrent_DIR=${QT_PATH}/lib/cmake/Qt5Concurrent \
    -D Qt5Core_DIR=${QT_PATH}/lib/cmake/Qt5Core \
    -D Qt5Gui_DIR=${QT_PATH}/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui \
    -D Qt5OpenGL_DIR=${QT_PATH}/lib/cmake/Qt5OpenGL \
    -D Qt5Test_DIR=${QT_PATH}/lib/cmake/Qt5Test \
    -D Qt5Widgets_DIR=${QT_PATH}/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets \
    -D _qt5gui_OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR=${SYSROOT_PATH}/opt/vc/include \
    -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_OPENCV_PYTHON2=OFF \
    -D BUILD_OPENCV_PYTHON3=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    .. | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/configure.log

echo -e ${Yellow}"Build OpenCV..."${Reset}
make -j${CORES} | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/make.log
make install | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/install.log

echo -e ${Yellow}"Upload /lib..."${Reset}
rsync -avz ${SYSROOT_PATH}/sysroot/lib root@${IP}:/ | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/copy_lib.log
ssh root@${IP} "chown -R root:root /lib"

echo -e ${Yellow}"Upload /usr/include..."${Reset}
rsync -avz ${SYSROOT_PATH}/sysroot/usr/include root@${IP}:/usr | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/copy_usr_include.log
ssh root@${IP} "chown -R root:root /usr/include"

echo -e ${Yellow}"Upload /usr/lib..."${Reset}
rsync -avz ${SYSROOT_PATH}/sysroot/usr/lib root@${IP}:/usr | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/copy_usr_lib.log
ssh root@${IP} "chown -R root:root /usr/lib"

echo -e ${Yellow}"Upload /opt/vc..."${Reset}
rsync -avz ${SYSROOT_PATH}/sysroot/opt/vc root@${IP}:/opt | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/copy_opt_vc.log
ssh root@${IP} "chown -R root:root /opt/vc"

echo -e ${Yellow}"Upload /usr/local..."${Reset}
rsync -avz ${SYSROOT_PATH}/sysroot/usr/local root@${IP}:/usr | tee ${TEMP_PATH}/log/upload_usr_local.log
ssh root@${IP} "chown -R root:root /usr/local"
```

But the build fails with the following error messages:

```
[ 99%] Building CXX object modules/stereo/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_stereo.dir/perf/perf_main.cpp.o
[ 99%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_stereo
[ 99%] Built target opencv_perf_stereo
[ 99%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_annotation
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libpng16.so.16, needed by /home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libz.so.1, needed by /home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libharfbuzz.so.0, needed by /home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libpcre2-16.so.0, needed by /home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libdouble-conversion.so.1, needed by /home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libgthread-2.0.so.0, needed by /home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libglib-2.0.so.0, needed by /home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_source_destroy'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_set_nominal_glyph_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_unicode_funcs_set_mirroring_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_jit_stack_create_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `renameat2@GLIBC_2.28'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_interlace_handling@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_source_set_can_recurse'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `crc32'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_face_destroy'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_compile_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_unicode_funcs_set_general_category_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_image_width@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_blob_create'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_set_ptem'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_unicode_funcs_create'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_jit_stack_assign_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_oFFs@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_main_context_new'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_unicode_funcs_set_eastasian_width_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_blob_get_empty'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `statx@GLIBC_2.28'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_source_remove_poll'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_set_glyph_h_advance_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_get_glyph_positions'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_get_glyph_infos'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_gray_to_rgb@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_PLTE@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_destroy'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `getentropy@GLIBC_2.25'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_match_context_free_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_unicode_funcs_destroy'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_is_immutable'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_create'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_text@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_source_unref'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_add_utf16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_face_is_immutable'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_set_font_h_extents_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_gAMA@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_filler@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_bgr@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_pattern_info_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_set_glyph_contour_point_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_face_set_index'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_valid@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_write_rows@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_unicode_funcs_set_decompose_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_main_context_default'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_set_ppem'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_face_create_for_tables'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_PLTE@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_sig_bytes@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_create'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_set_segment_properties'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_write_chunk@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_pHYs@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_match_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_unicode_funcs_set_decompose_compatibility_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_swap@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `compress2'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_unicode_funcs_set_combining_class_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_set_funcs'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_guess_segment_properties'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_x_pixels_per_meter@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_jit_compile_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_clear_contents'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_read_row@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_source_new'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_main_context_iteration'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_reverse'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_expand@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_option@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_set_flags'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_set_scale'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_allocation_successful'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_main_context_pending'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_pre_allocate'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_face_set_upem'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_set_variation_glyph_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `double_conversion::StringToDoubleConverter::StringToDouble(char const*, int, int*) const'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_tRNS@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_match_context_create_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_set_user_data'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_error_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_ot_layout_table_find_script'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_code_free_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Test.so.5: undefined reference to `fcntl@GLIBC_2.28'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_write_info@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_ot_tags_from_script'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_get_ovector_pointer_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_set_unicode_funcs'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_destroy'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_source_add_poll'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_shape_full'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_get_user_data'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_unicode_funcs_set_compose_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_get_error_message_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_destroy'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_substring_number_from_name_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_packing@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_main_context_wakeup'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_oFFs@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_read_end@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_read_update_info@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_get_length'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_config_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `deflate'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_write_image@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_make_immutable'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `uncompress'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_main_context_push_thread_default'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_y_pixels_per_meter@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_write_end@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_gamma@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_image_height@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_set_glyph_extents_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_main_context_ref'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_read_image@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_invert_mono@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_unicode_funcs_set_script_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `compress'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_read_info@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_match_data_free_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_create'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_get_channels@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_tRNS@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_gAMA@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_source_attach'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_error@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_main_context_pop_thread_default'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `hb_font_funcs_set_glyph_h_kerning_func'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `pcre2_jit_stack_free_16'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_packswap@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DoubleToAscii(double, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, int, char*, int, bool*, int*, int*)'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_text@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16@PNG16_0'
/home/kampi/Toolchain/RaspberryPi/sysroot/usr/local/RaspberryQt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `g_main_context_unref'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_annotation] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [apps/annotation/CMakeFiles/opencv_annotation.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

So it seems that some dependencies are missing, but I can not figure out how I can fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please provide how you cross compiled with qt on cent os? I tried about 9 different manuals and it took me weeks and always without success. Cross compiling for android is no problem - but rpi zero w gives me headake.. Thanks upfront